# Angular4 + MVC + cli + deployment using dist folder generated from cli build command

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, deployment, systemjs

I have an ***angular4 + MVC*** project.

I have a **dist** folder generated 
in angular through `ng build --prod` command in cli.

I want to eliminate ***node modules*** and checkin only these dist files for production.

*My problem is* how can i point to start execution using */dist* folder instead of */node modules*.

Currently i am using system.import() from my layout.cshtml(in mvc) to import app module of angular.

```
 <script>
System.import('app/main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
```

Also what should be the content in **systemjs.config** file since my intention is to eliminate node modules, and presently ** systemjs.config ** points to open node modules folder.

```
(function (global) {System.config({
paths: {
  'npm:': 'node_modules/'
},
map: {
  'app': 'app',
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
  '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
```

etc. etc.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This guide helped me: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/6-easy-steps-angular-5-visual-studio-irabanta-chingangbam

Comment: Exactly harini. this the way it is. you could have posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Its all about `index.html` in your build - which holds all your script part and polyfills

Just add your `index.html` from the dist folder to your `cshtml` file and map your script and style to the folder where you have your builds

you need to deploy only your prod build nothing more than that is required - you can exclude your node modules and check in your changes

Thanks !! Happy coding

Comment: thanks for the help though i found out the solution before and its working for me. 1) I ran `ng build` command to generate node files and startup files in dist folder. 2)removed node modules from project 3) add a bundle in cshtml file that points to all the files in dist folder / or simply add all the references of files in dist folder seperately to cshtml file. Run the code and it works fine